# How is the energy conservation principle preserved in the case mentioned below?

Tags: continuous-signals, signal-synthesis, signal-energy

Suppose there are 2 sinusoidal signals $\cos(\omega t)$ and $\cos(\omega t)$, which implies that their individual power is $1/2$ unit and total power is $1$ unit. When added, the signal $2\cos(\omega t)$, however, has power $2$ unit.

Obviously,

$$\rm Energy_{signal} = Power_{signal}\times Time_{period}$$

So, how does the principle of energy conservation hold in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power is homogeneous to a second degree quantity. When the data is doubled, the power is quadrupled.

The energy here (classicaly) is defined in an [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) as a squared $L_2$ norm, deriving from some [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, assuming a real Hilbert space,  $\|x\|^2 = \langle x,x\rangle$. Hence:  $$\|x+y\|^2 = \langle x+y,x+y\rangle = \|x\|^2 + 2\langle x,y\rangle+  \|y\|^2 \,.$$

Now set $y=x$, you gracefully get $\|x+x\|^2 = 4\|x\|^2$.

Comment: True. Power is proportional to the square of amplitude. I understand that. My question is regarding how energy is conserved in this case, That is, we had 2 individual cosine waves before. After passing them through a summer, the energy is more than the sum of their energies before passing them through the summer. How is this possible?

Comment: @Curiosity The adder is consuming power and delivering it in the form of the new signal.

Comment: Energy is not a simple conservative additive quantity. Imagine two signals $\cos \omega t$ and $-\cos \omega t$. Their sum will be zero energy. Why are  you ressorting to an energy conservation principle here?

Comment: Well, yes, that's my question. I mean, that's the part I don't get. Why should energy not be conserved here?

Comment: I mean, what is the process that consumes the energy?

Comment: I tried to precise how  energy is defined in most signal processing application

Comment: Okay, thanks for the insight. So, what I gather is that you mean to say that the principle of energy conservation (in the true sense of the term) does not apply to signals as such, because the concept of energy is somewhat different for them.

Comment: Somehow, because one should take into account the "angle" between signals. If you apply the given formula to a cosine minus a cosine, then you recover the "zero" energy as expected

Comment: True. I get your point. Thanks for the insight.